# How to fit and ODE to data?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, regression, linear-regression

Consider the following ODE
$$
y'(t)=\alpha x(t)-\beta y(t)
$$
and the following datasets
$$
X=\{(t_0,x_0),...,(t_n,x_n)\}\\
Y=\{(t_0,y_0),...,(t_n,y_n)\}
$$
How can I find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that best fits this data? In particular, is it possible to use the following solution
$$
y(t) = e^{-\beta t} \left( \alpha \int_0^t e^{\beta \tau} x(\tau) \, d\tau + C \right),
$$
directly, where $C$ is a constant?

**Thoughts:** This a fairly new field for me and I have briefly heard about [inverse problems in ODEs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00424), but rather than setting up a global minimizer that numerically finds it, I am wondering whether there is an analytical way of solving this problem, to the best possible fit in [some sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).

**Example:** As an example, one can consider the following data
$$
\begin{align}
X&=\{91, 110, 125, 105, 88, 84\}\\
Y&=\{1.0, 0.97, 1.0, 0.95, 0.92, 0.89\}
\end{align}
$$
at time points
$$
T=\{0, 5, 9, 18, 28, 38\}
$$
Using a [numerical approach](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) (see [Python script here](https://justpaste.it/edit/59288380/mc054bi18wz2e9mq)), I get the following fit

[image]

with $\alpha\simeq 0.000486$, $\beta\simeq 0.057717$, and a [chi-square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) of $0.0017296$. Is it possible to improve this? I have tried global optimizers, but to no avail, hence thinking of a potential analytical approach.

Comment: Regarding $x(t)$ the fitting is non-parametric. Do you need to identify $x(t)$ as well?

Comment: Can you joint to your question a representative numerical example of data.

Comment: @Cesareo The data I have regards both $x$ and $y$, so I guess I need to identify it as well.

Comment: @JJacquelin I have added an example, with a custom Python script.

Comment: The $x$ fit has nothing to do with the model parameters. In your code, you are fitting a 4th dergree polynomial, and the plot show that is a bad fit. It is no surprise that integrating a bad fit gives a similarly bad fit. Splines would be preferable, but I don't think you will get any good $x$ fit with so little data.

Comment: @whpowell96 I understand, and data is indeed scarce. If I consider some fit of $x$ (I considered a polynomial, but this is not imposed), how can I find $y,\alpha,\beta$ such that ODE is satisfied and I minimize my error? Perhaps I am phrasing the problem wrong. I simply want to find the best possible fit under reasonable choices for a regression on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

There is too little data to be able to come up with a decent fit. With the little data available, a fit must be made with few parameters to determine. In this sense, we first interpolate the data to $x(t)$ in spline form and continue with obtaining $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $y_0$ with a nonlinear least squares fit, on the solution of the integral that in this case can be obtained explicitly. The ideal would be to carry out the adjustment of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ simultaneously, but for this, a more significant data set would be necessary. Follows a MATHEMATICA script to accomplish that.

```
tk = {0, 5, 9, 18, 28, 38};
xk = {91, 110, 125, 105, 88, 84};
yk = {1, 0.97, 1, 0.95, 0.92, 0.89};
base[t_] := {1, t, t^2}
n = Length[tk];
X[t_] := Sum[base[t - tk[[k]]] . {a0[k], a1[k], a2[k]} (UnitStep[t - tk[[k]]] - UnitStep[t - tk[[k + 1]]]), {k, 1, n - 1}]
equsa1 = Table[base[tk[[k + 1]] - tk[[k]]] . {a0[k], a1[k], a2[k]} - a0[k + 1], {k, 1, n - 1}];
subsa1 = Solve[equsa1 == 0, Table[a2[k], {k, 1, n - 1}]][[1]];
equsa2 = Table[a1[k] + 2 a2[k] (tk[[k + 1]] - tk[[k]]) - a1[k + 1], {k, 1, n - 1}];
subsa2 = Solve[equsa2 == 0, Table[a2[k], {k, 1, n - 1}]][[1]];
equstot = Join[Join[equsa1, equsa2]];
varstot = Join[Join[Table[a1[k], {k, 1, n - 1}], Table[a2[k], {k, 1, n - 1}]]];
sols = Solve[equstot == 0, varstot][[1]];
Xt = X[t] /. sols;
subsvars = Table[a0[k] -> xk[[k]], {k, 1, n}];
Xt0 = Xt /. subsvars /. {a1[n] -> 0};
gr1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, xk}], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}];
Show[gr1, Plot[Xt0, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[n]]}], PlotRange -> All]
gr2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, yk}], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}];
```

[image]

```
tmax = tk[[n]]
Clear[x]
soly = DSolve[{y'[t] == alpha Xt0 - beta y[t], y[0] == y0}, y, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
yt = y[t] /. soly;
obj = Sum[((yt /. {t -> tk[[k]]}) - y2[[k]])^2, {k, 1, n}];
sol = Minimize[obj, {alpha, beta, y0}]

(** {0.000827948, {alpha -> 0.0000672746, beta -> 0.0102676, y0 -> 1.00217}} **)

yt0 = yt /. sol[[2]];
gr3 = Plot[yt0, {t, 0, tmax}];
Show[gr3, gr2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering, can you reduce the error if you don't force $x$ to go through the points? Finding a sweet spot between interpolation and the optimization problem?

Comment: To do that, we would consider $x(t,\theta)$ with $\theta$ a set of parameters. In this situation we would need much more data.

Comment: I understand. What if $x$ is a polynomial of a fixed degree (say 4)? It bugs me that I can't do better, but perhaps it is way harder than I initially thought.

Comment: With a fourth degree polynomial we need 5 parameters, plus three from the ode gives 8 parameters and we have data at 6 points. Anything can happen!

Comment: Think of it this way: $y(t)$ depends on the value of $x$ at all previous times. Given how sparse the data is, it's perhaps surprising that the error in $y$ is so low given how much of $x$ had to be interpolated. If this is real data, there is also the danger of overfitting, which reduces generalizability

Answer (score 1):

They are two data sets $(x,t)$ and $(y,t)$ to be fitted to two functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ respectively. Thus we need two equations in which some parameters have to be optimised.

In the wording of the problem only one equation is specified :
$$y'(t)=\alpha x(t)-\beta y(t)\tag1$$
in which two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to be optimised.

So one equation is missing. That is why (for example) a polynomial equation  might be proposed to approximate $y(t)$. With this additional equation the problem could be solved thanks to numerical calculus. But choosing a polynomial is rather arbitrary and the result will depend on the degree.

A different approach is proposed. This doesn't entirely solve the problem but leads directly to rough approximates of  $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Integrating the given equation $(1)$ leads to :

$$y(t)=y_0+\alpha \int_{t_0}^t x(\tau)d\tau-\beta \int_{t_0}^t y(\tau)d\tau\tag2$$
Approximates of the integrals can be computed thanks to numerical integration :

$$S_0=0\quad;\quad S_i=S_{i-1}+\frac12(x_i+x_{i-1})(t_i-t_{i-1})\quad \text{ from } i=1 \text{ to } i=n.$$
$$S_i\simeq\int_{t_0}^{t_i} x(\tau)d\tau$$

$$R_0=0\quad;\quad R_i=R_{i-1}+\frac12(y_i+y_{i-1})(t_i-t_{i-1})\quad \text{ from } i=1 \text{ to } i=n.$$
$$R_i\simeq\int_{t_0}^{t_i} y(\tau)d\tau$$
Approximate of Eq.$(2)$ gives the linear system :
$$y_i-y_0\simeq \alpha S_i-\beta R_i \quad \text{ from } i=0 \text{ to } i=n.\tag3$$
Linear regression gives approximates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

[image]

Of course this doesn't entirely solve the problem as pointed out at the begining of the answer. The functions $x(y)$ and $y(x)$ are not explicitely found. The modeling of the experiment should be completed. If not, one have to guess an additional equation possibly a convenient kind of function for $x(t)$ including parameters to optimise. This would be the most difficult part of the task even if approximates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are already known.

IN ADDITION : Example of fitting with a polynomial.

The choice of polynomials to approximate $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ might be not the best but the calculus is much simpler than with a no-elementary function.

Starting with the approximate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ computed above a linear regression leads to the coefficients of the polynomial.

Note : The magnitude of $x$ and $y$ are very different. It is simpler to choose LMSRE instead of LMSE as criteria of global fitting. This avoid rescaling.

Example :

$p =$ degree of the polynomial. (For example $p=5$).

$n =$ Number of points. (For example $n=6$).

[image]

[image]